# locally finite-help!

Tags: group-theory

Let be $V\leq \operatorname{Aut}\left( G\right),\ N\vartriangleleft G$ and $N$ is $V$-invariant.
Consider the semidirect product of $V$ with $G$. Let $C_{G}(V)=\{g\in G:g^{v}=g,\forall v\in V\}$. For finite groups the following applies:

> **(A)** If $(|V|,|G|)=1$, then $C_{G/N}(V)=C_{G}(V)N/N$.

The proof uses the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem and can be found in the book *An Introduction the Theory of Finite Groups*, Hans Kurzweil and Bernd Stellmacher.

I wish someone would present a **solution** to the case where G is locally finite group  such that $(|V|,|g|)=1,\forall g\in G$. Using **(A)**.

Remark: $G$ is locally finite group if $\forall H\leq G$, with $H$ finitely generated, then $H$ is finite.

One suggestion is to consider the subgroup $H=\langle a^{V}\rangle =\langle a^{v};v\in V\rangle$, with $a\in G$. We have $H$ is finite, because $G$ is finite locally. But even so, I can not a proof for the case locally finite. Just know that $C_{HN/N}(V)$ is isomorphic to $C_{H/H\cap N}(V)=C_{H}(V)(N\cap H)/N\cap H$ by **(A)**. But do not know why $aN\in C_{G/N}(V)$ would imply $aN \in C_{G}(V)N/N$ for all $a\in G$.

Grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just checking the definitions.

If $aN \in C_{G/N}(V)$ then for every $v \in V$, $a^v = a n_v$ for some $n_v = [a,v] \in N$. Note that $n_v = a^{-1} a^v \in H$, so that $a^v = a n_v$ for some $n_v \in N \cap H$. Hence $a(H \cap N) \in C_{H/(H \cap N)}(V)$. By **(A)**, $a = z n$ for some $z \in C_H(V)$ and $n \in N \cap H$. Clearly $z \in C_G(V)$ and $n \in N$, so $aN = znN = zN \in C_G(V) N /N$.

Comment: I am very grateful Jack Schmidt. I was thinking some time on this problem.